# Filtering interactive leaflet-map with dropdown-menu?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, filter, jquery, mapping

I try to set up a filterable "shot chart" like http://graphics.latimes.com/kobe-every-shot-ever/ with leaflet. I've a geojson file thats stores all the shots data, I've them showing up in a layer.

GEOJSON-Example:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "ID": 2,
    "SEASON_SHO": "1998-1999",
    "GAME_TYPE": "Regular",
    "PERIOD": 1,
    "MINUTES_RE": "06:25:00",
    "ACTION_TYP": "Jump Shot",
    "SHOT_TYPE": "2-PT-Wurf",
    "SHOT_DISTA": 15,
    "GAME_DATE": "05.02.1999",
    "HEIM": "SEA",
    "GAST": "DAL",
    "GEGNER": "Seattle SuperSonics",
    "SHOT_ATTEM": 1,
    "SHOT_MADE_": 0
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -0.314959,
      -0.159125
    ]
  }
}
```

I've set up an layer for all shots and a layergroup to filter the markers.

```
var url = 'data/Wuerfe.geojson';
var allewuerfe;

allewuerfe = L.geoJson(null, {

    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    style: style,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, allewuerfe);
    }
});

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    allewuerfe.addData(data);
});

var data = L.layerGroup([
    ]);
data.addLayer(allewuerfe);
data.addTo(map);
```

I already have some filters-buttons for single events, like "reset".

```
<button class="btn reset-btn" id="all">Reset</button>

document.getElementById("all").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    data.clearLayers();
    data.addLayer(allewuerfe);
    data.addTo(map);
});
```

But what I'd like to set up is an dropdown-filter for "shots missed", "shots hit" and "all shots".

```
           <select name="shot-result" class="custom-select" id="shotresult">
                <option value="all">All Shots</option>
                <option value="Made">Made</option>
                <option value="Missed">Missed</option>
            </select>
```

The data-info for that is stored in the geojson at "SHOT_MADE_", 1 means shot was made, 0 shot was missed.

I would like to get an code-example of how to get the filter work.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular scenario, I'd use the GeoJSON data to create several instances of `L.GeoJSON` (one per filter) and then use a `L.Control.Layers` to switch them off and on, something like:

```
fetch(geoJsonURL)
.then(function(response){ return response.json() })
.then(function(data){

  var missedShots = L.geoJson(data, { 
    filter: function(feature) { return feature.properties.SHOT_MADE_ == 0 }
  });

  var madeShots = L.geoJson(data, { 
    filter: function(feature) { return feature.properties.SHOT_MADE_ == 1 }
  });

  var allShots = L.layerGroup([madeShots, missedShots]);

  allShots.addTo(map);

  L.control.layers({
    "All shots": allShots,
    "Made shots": madeShots,
    "Missed shots": missedShots
  }).addTo(map);

});
```

Note that this method parses the GeoJSON data only once.

If you really want a drop-down menu instead of the default `L.Control.Layers`, then I encourage you to check out the [layer switchers section of the Leaflet plugins list](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#layer-switching-controls).

Using this technique over a lot of categories is also possible (pseudo-code follows, as I'm not sure how the teams would be structured:

```
var allTeams = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var teamLayers = { "All teams": allTeams };

for (var team in teams) {
   var teamLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
     filter: function(feat) { return feat.properties.team === team; }
   });
   var teamName = 'Team ' + team;
   allTeams.addLayer(teamLayer);
   teamLayers[ teamName ] = teamLayer;
}

L.control.layers(teamLayers).addTo(map);
```

Note how this is functionally the same as the other code block above, only using data structures that grow instead of hard-coded data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of filtering, I only show 2 options and start with one, then depending on which radio button selected, the data changes. 
http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/filter/filter.html

You basically have a layergroup, and on change, clear it and remove it from the map. Then

```
    myData.clearLayers();
    map.removeLayer(myData);
```

Then your layer has the filter in it's onEachFeature function:

```
    filter: function(feature, layer) {   
         return (feature.properties.SHOT_MADE_,  == 1 );
    },
```

Then you just add the layer to the layergroup and add it to the map.

Comment: Thanks Bill!
this works just fine to filter a couple of items, but I would also like to filter mulitple option-categorys like all teams (there are 30+ of them I'd like to store in a dropdown menu) - so for that, I need a different solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

With 30 some teams and several conditions using 2 select dropdowns, something like this may be better.

This is mostly pseudo code, two selects call one "Team", the other "Conditions", set the conditions to fire onchange="SelectPoints();"

```
//Using a Layer Group to add/ remove data from the map.
//initial setup your layer as "myLayer" and add it to the grouplayer.
var myData =  L.layerGroup([]);
    myData.addLayer(myLayer);
    myData.addTo(map); 

var selPts = [];

function SelectPoints(){
    var team = document.getElementById("Team").value;
    var cond= document.getElementById("Conditions").value;

    //Clear existing data 
    myData.clearLayers();
    map.removeLayer(myData);

    selPts.length =0;  //Reset the array if selecting new points

    myLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        // query  (Rough example/ something like this)
        if (  GEGNER  == team &&  SHOT_MADE_ ==cond  ) {
             selPts.push(layer.feature);  
        }
    });


    //Symbolize the Selected Points
         geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(selPts, {

            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                radius: 4, //expressed in pixels circle size
                color: "green", //or whatever
                stroke: true,
                weight: 7,      //outline width  increased width to look like a filled circle.
                fillOpcaity: 1
                });
                }
        });
        //Add selected points back into map as green circles.
        myData.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
        myData.addTo(map);
}
```